# SpecFlow BeforeScenario runs for each Feature file

Tags: c#, testing, bdd, specflow

I've only started to work with specflow and i know it's bindings are global for the assembly. Anyways, i couldn't find the solution or workaround for my problem:

1. I use abstract class for my UI tests, such as

   ```
   public abstract class UITestBase<T>
       where T : FeatureContext, new()
   {
       private static readonly object SyncObject = new object();
       private static AutoTestSettings settings;

       private IWebDriver webDriver;
       private IBrowserFactory browserFactory;
       private Container container;

       protected static T Context;

       [BeforeScenario]
       public virtual void BeforeScenario()
       {
           BuildConfiguration();

           var driverPool = container.GetInstance<IWebDriverPool>();
           webDriver = driverPool.GetDriver(settings.BrowserType);
           browserFactory = container.GetInstance<IBrowserFactory>();

           Context = new T
                         {
                             Browser = browserFactory.Create(webDriver, settings.WebsiteUrl, settings.BrowserType),
                             Container = container
                         };
       }

       [AfterScenario]
       public virtual void AfterScenario()
       {
           webDriver.Dispose();
       }
   }
   ```
2. I have few FeatureSteps files, one for  each page/feature. E.g LoginFeature and PurchaseFeature. Each FeatureSteps class extends UITestBase and has [Binding] attribute.
3. Whenever I run scenario for `LoginFeature` it seems to hook on `BeforeScenario` for `PurchaseFeatureSteps` as well. At least thats what `Debug.WriteLine(this.GetType().Name)` says.
4. It causes that each scenario opens as many browsers as there are inheritors of `UITestBase`. Although tests are running fine it looks sorta ugly and feels wrong.
5. Did anyone face such problem? How do I fix it?

Comment: The `BeforeScenario` attribute can be scoped to a tag I believe: `[BeforeScenario("myTag")]`. The `Binding` attribute itself doesn't take a scope, but alongside it you can apply the `Scope` attribute that can take a tag name.

Comment: But this code (initiating the IOC, starting the web driver) is common for every UI feature ever. Am I supposed to put before scenario method for every feature? That doesn't sound good as well.

Comment: I was commenting on your observation about global items, scoping helps negate that. We also fire up Selenium via Seleno in SpecFlow - I'll have a look to see how we've done it, but I'm certain it didn't involve `BeforeScenario`.

Comment: We maintain a browser host and `BeforeFeature` (tagged with the need to have a browser) we check if it is running, if not, we run it.

Comment: I wonder if I can use nunit attributes such as testfixture/setup/teardown with specflow scenarios. Nunit seems to work this things out.

Comment: @Adam, that sounds interesting. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Vladisav I would avoid doing that. SpecFlow can generate more than just NUnit tests, it also offers most hooks into a test that are necessary for stuff like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you noted, bindings are global in specflow. Also as you have discovered bindings in a base class are run once for each inheritor of that class. Don't place bindings into base classes, instead place them in a separate class specifically for this purpose, then Specflow will find them and run them. If you need to initialise objects for your scenarios to use, then I find its better to pass those objects through [specflow's prescribed ways of sharing data between bindings](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Sharing-Data-between-Bindings). I have outlined an approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26392380/nunit-specflow-how-to-share-a-class-instance-for-all-tests/26402692#comment50937280_26402692). My preference is for using context injection.

If you have some setup which is specific to particular features or scenarios, then the [bindings can be scoped](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Scoped-bindings) so that they only run for particular features or scenarions

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're very helpful. Although i don't like the concept of separate class (hard to maintain where the hooks are), it seems like legit solution.