# Selenium C# The name driver does not exist in the current context. I moved my variable to TestFixture class

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, bdd, specflow

Selenium C# I moved my driver variable from HomePage.cs class to the TestFixture.cs class because I want the browser variable to be instantiated in the setup of TestFixture.
E.g.

```
[SetUp]
public void FixtureSetup() {
        driver1 = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver1.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost:8080/searchtest");
}
```

I am getting the error:

```
The name driver 1 does not exist in the current context File: HomePage.cs
```

I think it cannot find the variable "driver1"
If i want to use this variable from the TestFixture class in other classes, HomePage.cs I thought if i define the var as public the other classes should be able to access the variable.

What is the best way I can solve this?
Should i put the "driver1" variable in a globals.cs class?

My code snippet is as follows:

class TestFixture.cs

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using SearchTest.Setup;
using earchTest.PageObjects;

namespace GoogleSearchTest.Setup
{
    [SetUpFixture]
    //public class TestConfiguration : SeleniumDriver
    public class TestConfiguration
    {
        public IWebDriver driver1;

        [SetUp]
        public void FixtureSetup()
        {
            driver1 = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver1.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost:8080/searchtest");
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void FixtureTearDown()
        {
            //if (WebDriver != null) WebDriver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Class HomePage.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using NUnit.Framework;
using SearchTest.Setup;



namespace SearchTest.PageObjects
{
    class HomePage : PageObjectBase 
    {
        //private IWebDriver driver{ get; set; }
        //private IWebDriver driver1 { get; set; }

        [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = ".//TITLE")]
        public IWebElement Title{ get; set; }

        // search text field on the homepage
        //[FindsBy(How= How.Id, Using="twotabsearchtextbox")]
        //private IWebElement Searchfield_ID { get; set; }

        [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = ".//*[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']")]
        private IWebElement Searchfield_XPATH { get; set; }

        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "nav-search-submit-text")]
        private IWebElement SearchButton { get; set; }

        [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = ".//*[@id='nav-search']/form/div[2]/div/input")]
        private IWebElement searchButton_Xpath {get; set;}


        public HomePage() : base("Title - Search Test")
        {
            //driver1 = new FirefoxDriver();
           //Console.Out.WriteLine("from Homepage Constructor Driver.title in SearchResultsPage class = " + driver.Title);
            //driver1.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)); // Set implicit wait timeouts to 5 secs
            PageFactory.InitElements(driver1, this);
        }

    public void goToURL() {
        //driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        //driver1.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost:8080/searchtest");
    }

    public void EnterSearchText(String text) {
            Searchfield_XPATH.SendKeys(text);
    }

    public SearchResultsPage click_search_button() {
        searchButton_Xpath.Click();
        return new SearchResultsPage(driver1);
    }

    }   
}
```

Class PageObjectBase.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

/* The PageObjectBase class.  This class is to represent anything that applies to all pages
* of the site to be tested.  The example here shows that you can pass in by default a
* Title from the driver to ensure that the correct page is loaded, but the intention * of this is to provide a base class so that codereplication is kept to a minimum
*/

namespace SearchTest.PageObjects
{
    class PageObjectBase
    {
        private IWebDriver Driver { get; set; }

        //public PageObjectBase(IWebDriver driver,String titleOfPage)
        public PageObjectBase(String titleOfPage)
        {
            //Driver = driver;
            Driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            Console.Out.WriteLine("From base class driver.title = " + Driver.Title);
            //if (Driver.Title != titleOfPage)
            //    throw new NoSuchWindowException("PageObjectBase: The Page Title doesnt match.");
        }
    }
}
```

In my Python code i have the SetUp as follows, how to do it in C#?:

BaseTestCase.py

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from Locators import Globals
from Pages import login
import time
import os

class BaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER["unexpectedAlertBehaviour"] = "accept"
        cls.driver = webdriver.Ie(Globals.IEdriver_path)
        cls.driver.get(Globals.URL_riaz_pc)
        cls.login_page = login.LoginPage(cls.driver)
        cls.driver.implicitly_wait(120)
        cls.driver.maximize_window()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        time.sleep(5)
        cls.login_page.click_logout()
        cls.driver.close()
        # kill the IEDriverServer process because it stays left open when test finishes.  Multiple instances will remain otherwise every time a test runs.
        print "Kill process IEDriverServer.exe"
        os.system('taskkill /f /im IEDriverServer.exe')
```

Globals.py

```
IEdriver_path = "C:\Webdriver\IEDriverServer\IEDriverServer.exe"
URL_riaz_pc = "http://riaz-pc.company.local:8080/clearcore"
URL_test1 = "http://test1:8080/clearcore"
```

I am trying to follow a page object model in C# as I want to use BDD Specflow instead of Behave in Python.

My E.g. Steps file is:

```
using System;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using NUnit.Framework;
using SearchTest.PageObjects;

namespace SearchTest
{
    [Binding]
    public class SearchSteps
    {
        private IWebDriver driver { get; set; }
        PageObjects.HomePage home_page { get; set; }
        private SearchResultsPage search_results_page;

    [Given(@"I navigate to the page ""(.*)""")]
    public void GivenINavigateToThePage(string p0)
    {
        //driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        //driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost:8080/searchtest");
        home_page = new PageObjects.HomePage();
        //home_page.goToURL();
    }

    etc...
```

Thanks,
Riaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using specflow then you shouldn't be using the NUnit attributes to control test ligfecycle ( ie `[Setup]`, `[TearDown]` etc, you should instead use the specflow options for controlling test lifecycle, (ie `[BeforeScenario]`, `[BeforeFeature]` etc). Mixing them can just cause issues which are awkward to track down.

To answer your question though specflow provides a number of ways to share data between bindings. Read [this for more details](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Sharing-Data-between-Bindings).

Some details of how you can do this using context injection are used in my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26392380/nunit-specflow-how-to-share-a-class-instance-for-all-tests/26402692#comment50937280_26402692) and this should give you enough details to be able to see how to share the web driver.

Comment: Thanks very much for pointing me to the right information.  I understand now and will use the recommended steps you have suggested.